# Circle in password field using CSS

Tags: html, css, input

Here is the code, this does not work in Chrome:

```
<input type="password" name="pass" style="
        -webkit-text-security: circle;
        " />
```

What code can I use to make it work?

Comment: I don't think using css3 text-security is a good idea since it can be converted from "circle" to "none" on firebug or any inspect element browser features

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the text security mark-up of a type password input because of security considerations.  You can however mark-up a text input field to have it use the circle style so it behaves and functions exactly like a password field

```
<input type="text" name="pass" style="-webkit-text-security: circle">
```

Comment: @JamesWebster How does this not answer the question?  The webkit text security mark-up can't be used to change the text hashing.  If the OP wants to achieve the same effect, he has to use a type text input

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<p><input type=text /></p>
<p><input type=text /></p>
<p><input type=text /></p>
<p><input type=text /></p>

<p><input type=password /></p>
<p><input type=password /></p>
<p><input type=password /></p>
<p><input type=password /></p>

<div class="important">
<p><input type=text /></p>
<p><input type=text /></p>
<p><input type=text /></p>
<p><input type=text /></p>

<p><input type=password /></p>
<p><input type=password /></p>
<p><input type=password /></p>
<p><input type=password /></p>
</div>
```

and **use this css...**  (select the one you want)

```
p:nth-of-type(4n) input{-webkit-text-security:circle;}
p:nth-of-type(4n+1) input{-webkit-text-security:none;}
p:nth-of-type(4n+2) input{-webkit-text-security:square;}
p:nth-of-type(4n+3) input{-webkit-text-security:disc;}


.important p:nth-of-type(4n)  input[type="password"]{ -webkit-text-security: circle !important;}
.important p:nth-of-type(4n+1) input[type]{-webkit-text-security:none  !important;}
.important p:nth-of-type(4n+2) input[type]{-webkit-text-security:square  !important;}
.important p:nth-of-type(4n+3) input[type]{-webkit-text-security:disc  !important;}
```

hope it helps

If this isn't working in your Webkit browser it is because the User Agent stylesheet has the following code:

```
input[type="password"] { -webkit-text-security: disc !important;}
```

while you can overwrite CSS in your UA StyleSheet, you can't overwrite an !important in your UA CSS